# Calculating % of COUNT with groupby function in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Running into some issues figuring out how to add in an extra column that will give me the percentage of the total of the aggregate of the count function. The query I have looks like this:

```
    Select
       count(*) AS num_rides,
       member_casual
    FROM `2020_bikeshare_data`
    GROUP BY member_casual
    ORDER BY num_rides DESC
```

And returns me this result:

| num_rides | member_casual |
| --- | --- |
| 2134988 | member |
| 1341217 | casual |

And what I'd like to do is add a 3rd column that lists the percent of the total each membership makes up

| num_rides | member_casual | perc_tot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2134988 | member | 61.4% |
| 1341217 | casual | 38.6 |

thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You window functions:

```
SELECT member_casual,
       COUNT(*) AS num_rides,
       COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()
FROM `2020_bikeshare_data`
GROUP BY member_casual
ORDER BY num_rides DESC;
```

No subquery is needed.

Comment: This worked out great. I'm not sure I understand how though? I'm new to all this jazz and learning, thanks for your help (again)

Comment: @PeterFonteneau . . . Window functions are definitely something you should learn about:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts.  If there BQ documentation isn't clear, there is a lot of other documentation on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select distinct member_casual,
  count(num_rides) over type as num_rides,
  round(count(num_rides) over type * 100.0 / count(num_rides) over(), 2) as perc_tot
from `2020_bikeshare_data`
window type as (partition by member_casual)
# order by num_rides desc
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the subquery, get the total number of rows and calculate the percentage accordingly.

```
 Select
       count(*) AS num_rides,
       member_casual,
       Concat(count(*) * 100 / totalRecord,' %') as perc_tot
  FROM (SELECT *,COUNT(*) as totalRecord FROM `2020_bikeshare_data`) 
  GROUP BY member_casual
```

or

```
Select
       count(*) AS num_rides,
       member_casual,
       Concat(count(*) * 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `2020_bikeshare_data`) ,' %') as perc_tot
FROM `2020_bikeshare_data`
GROUP BY member_casual
```

Comment: Does this syntax work in BigQuery? ANSI SQL will throw an error for your subquery for including a column in your SELECT without being part of the aggregate.

Comment: It should work because there is no specific syntax

Comment: No, that sub-query (in the first code snippet) will Not run in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is use a subquery as part of the  column expression to calculate your percentage:

```
select 
    count(1) as num_rides,
    member_casual,
    sum(100) / (select sum(1.0) from `2020_bikeshare_data`) as perc_tot -- return as percentage
from
    `2020_bikeshare_data`
group by
    member_casual
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you can also break this down into simple SQL (without window functions) by organizing with CTEs.

```
with 
    data as (select * from `2020_bikeshare_data`),
    total as (select count(*) as ride_count from data),
    by_type as (select member_casual, count(*) as ride_count from data group by 1)
select
    member_casual,
    by_type.ride_count as num_rides,
    by_type.ride_count / total.ride_count as perc_tot
from by_type
cross join total
```

In my opinion, this is much easier to see the `perc_tot` calculation.